# PHP variable is empty only in fwrite

Tags: php, fwrite

I think I'm going crazy.

code:

```
<?
$meh = $_GET["q"];
echo ( ":" . $meh . ":" . strlen($meh) . PHP_EOL );
$fp = fopen("/tmp/wtf.log","w+");
fwrite($fp, ":" . $meh . ":" . strlen($meh) . PHP_EOL );
fclose($fp);
?>
```

request:

```
/search.php?q=meh123
```

This is in the response ( expected ):

```
:meh123:6
```

This is in the file:

```
me@host:/tmp# cat wtf.log 
::0
```

Comment: How sure are you that you're the only one that accessed it? That it's writing to the file at all?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe try adding parenthesis or saving the string to a variable? `(":" . $meh . ":" . strlen($meh) . PHP_EOL)` or `$str = ":" . $meh . ":" . strlen($meh) . PHP_EOL; fwrite( $fp, $str);`

Comment: Have you tried using the a+ mode to see if you're writing each time?

Comment: As Ignacio said, it could be another request zeroing it out.. try putting if(isset($_GET['q'])) { // code } around your code (something you should be doing anyway ;)

Comment: Check the return value of fopen. My theory is that it worked once but failed to write the actual variables for some reason, but now you have a permission problem. (this could happen if you ran it on the web, opened it in an editor and saved it when you closed) You think it runs but it's failing so you're just seeing the same thing the file had in it when it was originally written.

Comment: @GigaWatt well he posts the response, which is the result of the echo

Comment: What is the output command of `ls -l /tmp/wtf.log` ?

Comment: @Jay - I'm not entirely sure how I missed that.  Thanks much.

Comment: @GigaWatt I just spent hours debugging a problem in a DirectX project of mine which turned out to be a misplaced curly brace so, no worries ;)

Comment: The permissions on the file are fine, as you can see the script is successfully writing to it. This also indicates that the fopen is succeeding. And no there are no other accesses "Stomping" on my tests. I am the only one hitting it, and I verify this with apache's access.log. Additionally, I have tried rm'ing the file before each attempt, same results. I am terribly confused but this...

Comment: Any chance you guys can upvote this question since its stumping us? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?
$meh = $_GET["q"];
$writeline = ":{$meh}:{strlen($meh)}";
echo ( $writeline );
$fp = fopen("/tmp/wtf.log","w+");
fwrite($fp, $writeline );
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Also, as Jay said in the comment above:

> try putting if(isset($_GET['q'])) { // code } around your code (something you should be doing anyway)

Comment: I attempted to narrow down the behavior to the minimal code needed to demonstrate it. $_GET['q'] is set, which is apparent when it's echoed to the output.

Comment: Did you try this way to see if it works, though? (not the isset part, but the other part)

Comment: Yep, just now, same thing! Although the way you put it its even more... disturbing, right? I also added a var_dump($writeline) at the very end of yours and it looks normal: string(10) ":meh123:6 "

Comment: Same result. I posted to the php-general mailing list with no success. I did learn from apache's error.log that on line 2, where we assign to $writeline, there is a warning that q is an invalid index. Despite the fact that we obtain and use that value in echo() and it is indeed defined. I'm going to submit a report to bugs.php.net.